# SSRS Report Error : Error During processing of Command Text Expression of Dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to call a parameter in SSRS (This is being loaded based off of a view from Redshift not Stored Procedure). So, I am trying to call the parameter in report as an expression after my select statement and after my select statement I am calling them in the where clause. But getting a command text expr error. May I know what can be done in this scenario or where am I committing a mistake?

```
select
manager_id,
manager_name,
employee_name,
employee_number from emp
WHERE  (employee_number =" +Parameters!EMPNum.Value + ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question but if this is just a dataset query then set the dataset to text and use the following query statement

```
select
manager_id,
manager_name,
employee_name,
employee_number from emp
WHERE  employee_number = @EMPNum
```

The parameter value will be parsed in the dataset query without doing anything else